# Sitecore SXA Item Query and sort capability

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to figure out how to go about defining a sort when building a query for an item query (this is driving the results of an SXA page list).  When in the query builder, I see that sort is an option, but it's unclear after typing sort: what the builder is expecting next.  A GUID of a field to sort?  Also, I am not finding any kind of documentation talking about if you are able to define ascending / descending in the sort or really anything about it other than it's existence.  If anyone has some background on this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

This is Sitecore specific, not SXA. When you build a query you need to specify a field that will be used for sorting. Then when you click on the sort icon you can change it to descending or ascending.

Here is a quick demo

[image]

I just build a query to search for items of template `Blog Post` and sort them using custom field: `Published` (DateTime)

The raw values of my queries are:

- `+template:{efa62406-cfd7-43c6-b702-3f53dfb1cee3};sort:published`
- `+template:{efa62406-cfd7-43c6-b702-3f53dfb1cee3};sort:published[desc]`

I am not sure where you put your query (directly into a data source field or on item) but recommended location is **ItemQuery** item (`/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Item Queries/YOURITEM`)

I published a few days ago a blog post which touches this topic. You could learn how to do it by reading [Item Queries section](https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog#item-queries).

You will also find step by step instruction how to configure sorting for `Search Results` in case you switch from `Page List`.

Comment: This is great detail.  I think part of my confusion is that my Sitecore site is actually not giving me predictive options based on what I am typing.  I'd be curious to see what the sort portion of the query you put together looks like.  I assume it's +template:{guid};+sort{?} Also, are you aware of being able to define if it will sort ascending or descending based on the field you enter?

Comment: @DavidHake answer updated with raw values of my crafted queries. Yes, I presented two cases on the gif (descending/ascending)

Comment: Thank you!  One last question, are you aware of being able to sort on any custom fields, or is it limited to fields on a standard Sitecore item?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Custom fields from template or custom field types? If the first, then the answer is yes. I used `Published` field which comes from my custom template and it is not a default Sitecore field, I've created templates from the scratch. Default types like date, integer have proper comparer already, I've never created a comparer for custom field types and I don't know for now how to do it. Btw. do you really need that?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a custom field in a template I've created.  If I define a template in my query I am searching for, should the sort make all the fields available in that template for me to sort against?

Comment: Yes. While you specify sort field there is a query in the background which returns all fields, not only those which exist in your template (used for previous filter criteria).
Technically you can require sorting by a field which is not present in some of the search results.
Open chrome dev tools and type space then remove text completely. 
Look for a request like that `http://site/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/ItemBucket.asmx/GetFields`. My response contains more than 1000 fields.